# How to install python aruco module on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, python, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV aruco libraries using python 2.7.  I have OpenCV 3.2 installed on my raspberry pi 3.

The problem is I am neither able to import aruco module in my python code nor use it via cv2 (for ex. `cv2.aruco`). I am new to python and to aruco. 
 Can anybody please explain how can I install aruco python modules or there is any other way I can  use these?

Answer (score 2):

When compiling OpenCV library you have to manually set up in the compile settings to compile python bindings. Just install cmake-gui and compile OpenCV using that. When you enter cmake-gui you have tab configure and there just search for Python bindings and set it to true.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have already installed cv2 on pi and am able to compile programs using OpenCV features . My doubt is how can I install the aruco module on raspberrypi 3 . If I am missing anything , please correct me .